# How to implement a UI like News Feed View in Facebook app

Tags: facebook, layout, user-interface, ios6, view

That's the question I'm wondering from around 2 weeks. How to implement a complex UI like News Feed from Facebook iOS app?.
I come from web development (.NET using MVC.NET) and I do not know for sure which is the way to implement a rich and complex UI with partial views as we do using xhtml views and theirs controllers. I think it cannot be done using UIB but might I code all that stuff?. And what kind of UI components could I use to get that (tables with some views inside o is there any other type of UI elements to build this kind of interfaces)?.

Thank you

[image]